# My R bar chart is not showing the last number?

Tags: r

I am a new learner of R and I had problem showing the last number "11" in my horizontal bar chart in R. Here I am attaching my code below. It'd be greatly appreciated if someone can point me the right direction, thanks a lot!

```
## horizontal bar chart 
stu <- c(11,10,4,1) 
col <- c("Brown","Blue","Green","Gray") 
bplot <- barplot(stu,
                 names.arg=col,
                 main="Eye Color Horizontal Bar Chart",
                 horiz = TRUE,
                 beside = TRUE) 
zi <- as.matrix(stu) 
text(zi+0.25,bplot,labels = zi)
```

And my plot looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Increase the limits on x-axis to a number higher than your maximum number :

```
stu <- c(11,10,4,1) 
col <- c("Brown","Blue","Green","Gray") 
bplot <- barplot(stu, names.arg=col,
                      main="Eye Color Horizontal Bar Chart",
                      horiz = TRUE,beside = TRUE, xlim = c(0, max(stu) + 2)) 
zi <- as.matrix(stu) 
text(zi+0.25,bplot,labels = zi)
```

[image]